# Rails I can't use belongs_to and class name methods correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

First of all, good forum to all.
I am trying to develop an application with Ruby on rails and in this application there will be User and Room classes and these classes will communicate with each other with winner_id and creator_id, but I could not do the necessary actions, can you help?

Creating a user model:

```
$ rails g model User first_name last_name username role player_id:integer password
```

Creating a room model:

```
$ rails g model Room rules:text online:boolean room_id:integer password:string winner:belongs_to creator:belongs_to
```

User.rb:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :oda,class_name:"Room",foreign_key:"owner_id"
    has_many :winner,class_name:"Room",foreign_key:"winner_id"
end
```

Room.rb:

```rb
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner,class_name:"User",foreign_key:"owner_id"
  belongs_to :winner,class_name:"User",foreign_key:"winner_id"
end
```

The code I'm trying to run:

```rb
User.all

[#<User:0x00005598a714d120
  id: 1,
  first_name: "Lorem",
  last_name: "İpsum",
  username: "Wormer",
  role: "janitor",
  player_id: 1234,
  password: "[FILTERED]",
  created_at: Thu, 10 Feb 2022 15:54:15.312134000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 10 Feb 2022 15:54:15.312134000 UTC +00:00>,
 #<User:0x00005598a71b8060
  id: 2,
  first_name: "Hello",
  last_name: "World",
  username: "MoonKnight",
  role: "player",
  player_id: 1234,
  password: "[FILTERED]",
  created_at: Thu, 10 Feb 2022 15:55:09.787504000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 10 Feb 2022 15:55:09.787504000 UTC +00:00>] 

room = Room.new do |room|
  room.rules = "None"
  room.online = true
  room.password = "a"
  room.room_id = 5555
end

room.winner = User.find_by(role:"player")
room.creator = User.find_by(role:"janitor")
room.save
```

Error:

```rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:147:in `initialize': SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.owners (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:147:in `initialize': no such table: main.owners (SQLite3::SQLException)
```

Comment: This isn't reproducable so I would guess that its some sort of "slop error", you might have an unsaved file or you haven't reloaded the classes in the console after saving the file.

Comment: You also don't need the `foreign_key` option the `belongs_to` assocations since they can be derived from the name.

Comment: Can you add your `schema.rb`?

Comment: You have issue with winner at one relationship you are saying winner is room, where in other one you are mention it user object. And in migration you have not mention about it. `has_many :winner,class_name:"Room"` and `has_many :winner,class_name:"Room",foreign_key:"winner_id"` can you check and make it proper relationship.

Comment: @KamalPanhwar can you share an example please.

Comment: Have you run the migration?

Comment: Yes i tried to run it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating the Room model like this:

```rb
class CreateRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :rooms do |t|
      t.text :rules
      t.boolean :online
      t.integer :room_id
      t.string :password
      t.belongs_to :winner, null: false# remove,foreign_key:true
      t.belongs_to :creator, null: false# remove,foreign_key:true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :rooms, :users, column: :winner_id
    add_foreign_key :rooms, :users, column: :creator_id
  end
end
```

User.rb:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :winner_rooms,class_name:"Room",foreign_key:"winner_id"
    has_many :creator_rooms,class_name:"Room",foreign_key:"creator_id"

end
```

Room.rb:

```rb
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :winner,class_name:"User",foreign_key:"winner_id"
  belongs_to :creator,class_name:"User",foreign_key:"creator_id"

end
```

Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).